# Upgrade react native from 0.12 to 0.15 got null pointer error

Tags: react-native

I tried to upgrade react native on android from 0.12 to 0.15,but I got a nullpointerException when I start my app.

Is there any break up changes?Do I need to change my code?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7074)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3976)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3788)
        at com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager.updateExtraData(ReactTextViewManager.java:85)
        at com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager.updateExtraData(ReactTextViewManager.java:37)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.updateViewExtraData(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:110)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UpdateViewExtraData.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:183)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:574)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:622)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:120)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:786)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
```

Any Idea to solve this problems?

Answer (score 0):

In your project,open `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file,change last line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip`.

When I change the gradle version to `gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`, everything works fine.

If `gradle-2.4-all.zip` does not work,you can try replace other version,[click here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions) for more.